# sending cURL request to another machine gives connection refused

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

On my one machine(m1) elasticsearch is installed and on my other machine (m2) it's not. I want to send cURL request to m1 on which E.S is running. I am using this query

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XGET "10.10.10.149:9200/bigmart/dotnet/_search?pretty" -d ' { "query":{"match_all":{}}}'
```

it gives me

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.10.10.149 port 9200: Connection refused
```

I can ping and ssh to that machine , but I can't send cURL to that machine, what am I missing ?

I can do localhost:9200 successfully, so I gues port 9200 is open. I am missing something, I don't know exactly what

Comment: Your firewall is probably blocking port 9200 for outside access. What do you get when you run `iptables -L` as root on m1?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the IP of the machine they you have a firewall blocking that machine. Firewalls don't allows block requests from the loopback address.